# Is it possible to predict a whole output vector given an input vector or a series of vectors using XGBoost?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp

I have text dataset of text reviews and answers. Each sentence of the reviews and answers have been vectorized like this:

```
                    Vector_Review                                       Answer_Vector
0   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]   [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
3   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4   [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I have made up the vectors to give an example, i know they do not match as expected, but imagine the review vectors and the answer vectors match.

The vectors of the sentences have been created using `one-hot` matches based on a built vocabulary set extracted from the reviews/answers texts. When a review keyword appears on its answer, then it will be 1, if not, 0.

Now i would like to make a few questions. Imagine each review vector is associated with its corresponding answer vector:

- 1. Is there a way to predict the whole answer vector given a new review vector?
- 2. Is there any ML algorithm that could take an input vector like this and output a new vector?
- 3. Is this possible with XGboost or any other existing algorithm?
- 4. Would it be possible/better with a neural network?
- 5. What could be the best approach to tackle this problem if not?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll summarize the answer to all the questions as a single one:

Given an input text you can use statistical distribution and inferred syntatics and semantics to predict a second text.

This has been done with much success recently with the Seq2Seq model.

In summary, seq2seq is a neural network model (it was commonly made on top of a recursive neural network - RNN) composed of an Encoder and a Decoder. Usually this works based on embeddings, but it seems that it wont be hard to turn your one-hot-encodings into embeddings.

There have been several outbreaks to this model with the use of the so-called Attention mechanisms (and Google BERT).

Hence, this is usually better done using Artificial Neural Networks

Here are some references to start with:

- BERT: https://ai.googleblog.com/2018/11/open-sourcing-bert-state-of-art-pre.html
- Seq2Seq: https://google.github.io/seq2seq/
- Attention: https://www.google.com/search?q=attention+mechanism&oq=attention+mechanism&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j35i39l2j0l2j69i60.2606j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
- RNN: https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-rnn-and-lstm-f7cdf6dfc14e

Comment: Thank you very much Tiago. This is pretty much the orientation i needed. I'm quite new to NLP and i was wondering which could be the best way to proceed when predicting sequences of texts given another text sequence. I'll have a look at your suggestions. I hope this can take me to my goals here :)